# Perl Regex issue via Python Script

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, subprocess

We have ran into a problem when running a python script on a unix box that calls a perl command that uses regex to replace a password in a properties file.

```
var= folderHome+"/conf/cs.properties"
process = subprocess.call(["perl", "-i", "-pe", "s/(?<=password=)\w+/\1mynewordtesting/", var])
```

When using the python segment below it replaces the password just fine but will add an 'SOH' char as shown below

[image: 'SOH' Problem]

But using the same command directly in commandline will correctly replace the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the `\1` to `\\1`; Python sees that as an escape sequence for the hex byte `01`:

```
>>> '\1'
'\x01'
```

So:

```
process = subprocess.call([
    "perl", "-i", "-pe",
    "s/(?<=password=)\w+/\\1mynewordtesting/", var])
```

Alternatively, use a raw string literal; escape sequences are then ignored:

```
process = subprocess.call([
    "perl", "-i", "-pe", 
    r"s/(?<=password=)\w+/\1mynewordtesting/", var])
```